# Send Email from Localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, email, sendmail, sendmail.exe

May I know how to send an email from localhost to gmail or other email accounts? I already make research regarding this matter and tried to do it but still can not send the email. Below are my `sendmail.ini` and `php.ini` files that I edit,

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=khairulamran.nazri@gmail.com
auth_password=[email password]
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=khairulamran.nazri@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

**php.ini** - mail function

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

**contact.php** - to send the email

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $to=$_POST['email'];
    $hp=$_POST['hp'];
    $subject="Test";
    $msg="Thank you for Register. Your Name is ".$name." and Hp no. is ".$hp;
    $header="khairulamran.nazri@gmail.com";
    $success=mail($to,$subject,$msg,$header);
    if($success==true){
        echo "Email send successfully ";
    } else{
        echo "Error sending email";
    }
}
?>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="">
Nama:<input type="text" name="name"><p>
Email:<input type="text" name="email"><p>
Hp:<input type="text" name="hp">
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If click Submit, it will not send the email that have been submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use mailer library. I had used and it will work perfectly.
Follow this. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

You would need to only enter your gmail credentials and after that it will work.

Comment: want to reconfirm, if I use mailer library, do I still need to edit the php.ini and sendmail.ini file?

Comment: No, you will only need to fill information in mailer library.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my case. Hope it will be useful if someone need information regarding this case as well.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $to=$_POST['email'];
    $hp=$_POST['hp'];

    require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->setFrom('khairulamran.nazri@gmail.com', 'Amran');
    $mail->addAddress($to);               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('khairulamran.nazri@gmail.com', 'Information');
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Test Email';
    $mail->Body    = 'Body of message goes here';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Body of message goes here<for non html mail client>';
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}
?>

<form name="contact" method="post" action="">
Nama:<input type="text" name="name"><p>
Email:<input type="text" name="email"><p>
Hp:<input type="text" name="hp">
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit">
</form>
```